# xsl 1.0 split elements into two diffrent tables

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Hi I'm new in XSLT programming and I'm using the XSLT 1.0 version
I have xml file that I want to transfer to HTML table.
The issue is how to copy the nodes with  element into another table?

Here is the XML input

```
<root>    
    <element>
        <id> 1 </id>
        <data> aa </data>
    </element>

    <element>
        <id> 2 </id>
        <err> y </err>
        <data> bb </data>

    </element>

    <element>
        <id> 3 </id>
        <data> cc </data>
    </element>

    <element>
        <id> 4 </id>
        <err> x </err>
        <data> dd </data>
    </element>
</root>
```

Here is the expected output:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Error </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> 2 </td>
            <td> y </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 4 </td>
            <td> x </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <thead>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Data </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> 1 </td>
            <td> aa </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 2 </td>
            <td> bb </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 3 </td>
            <td> aa </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 4 </td>
            <td> bb </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using XSLT 1.0
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: If you are using XSLT 1.0, then don't tag your question as XSLT 2.0. Also, please take the time to post a **well-formed** input.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in stackoverflow, I fixed the tag and add the root tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple, albeit verbose way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Error</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="root/element[err]">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="err"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>                
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Data</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="root/element">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="data"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>                
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's a somewhat smarter way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Error</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/element/err"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>                
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Data</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/element/data"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>                
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="err|data">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="../id"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above assumes a **well-formed** input, having a root element named `<root>`.